# VS2010 add a .dll reference error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll

I am trying to add a DLL to my project but there are some problems.
first of all, VS dont compile when I add the dll in references. it shows the error :

The "NativeAssemblies=@(NativeReferenceFile);@(_DeploymentNativePrerequisite)" parameter for the "ResolveManifestFiles" task is invalid.

The "ResolveManifestFiles" task could not be initialized with its input parameters.

anyone can tell me what is wrong ?

Comment: Is it a valid COM or Managed Library? what is name of dll?

Comment: What DLL are you referencing? What kind of project?

Answer (score 1):

A similar question was asked previously.  You can refer to the links below to see if it helps alleviate your errors.

[See this StackOverflow question : ResolveManifestFiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102163/what-causes-the-error-the-resolvemanifestfiles-task-failed-unexpectedly-illeg)

[MSDN Forums - Discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/a92bad5e-3a5a-4605-ac2d-03447869892e)

[Regsvr32 Usage and Errors](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/249873)

Comment: I have seen those threads already.
I tryed to register the dll with regsvr32.exe but that gives an error like :
"The module "C:\ ....   LDACTL.dll" was loaded but the entry point DllRegisterServer was not found."
"Make sure that "C:\ ... LDACTL.dll" is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try again"

the dll dont have any problem ? for being in native assembley or something like that?

Comment: @CristóvãoMacedo : Regsvr32.exe was unable to find the required entrypoint in the module specified in the command line. This can occur if the entrypoints are not properly exported from the module or if the module is not a .DLL or .OCX file.

Comment: @CristóvãoMacedo : I've added an additional link to my answer.  It provides an overview of Regsvr32 usage and error codes.

Answer (score 0):

I have already resolved the problem.

first, the dll isn´t a .NET dll so I has to put it in bin/debug directory of project folder.

then I access it with :

```
[DllImportAttribute(@".\LDACTL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    static extern int LDA_GetStatus();
```

LDA_GetStatus() is a function on dll....